# Reading part of pcap file in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I've been trying to figure out a way to read a part of a pcap-file using scapy.

**Ex:** I have a pcap-file with 1000 rows.

**Question:** Is it possible to read this in 10 pieces, i.e. read 100 rows sequentially?

The scenario is:

I'm reading multiple pcap files and comparing packets between them.
In order to compare packets, I use index and call a specific packet as `pkt = packets_from_pcap_file_7[idx]`. To use index I need to read the pcap-files with `rdpcap(FILENAME.pcap)`. However, this function will read the entire pcap-file and cause a MemoryError.

Since I want to compare specific packets from different files, I find it hard to use
`RawPcapReader(FILENAME.pcap)` where I can just iterate through one specific packet at the time as:

```
packets = RawPcapReader(FILENAME.pcap)
for pkt in packets:
    pkt.doThings
```

I will post a very slow solution to the problem we're I have to iterate through the entire pcap-file for every packet and iterate to a specified index:

```
def get_packet(idx):
    packets = RawPcapReader("FILENAME.pcap")
    counter = 0
    for pkt in packets:
        if counter == idx:
            return pkt
        counter += 1
```

I could split the packets in the linux terminal but since this will be used for others as well, I would like the scripts to do all the job.
I think there is a much simpler solution to this, which I've been unable to find. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably open all the files without reading them, then iterate through the packets. Something like

```
files = ["a.pcap", "b.pcap", ......]
fds = [RawPcapReader(x) for x in files]
while True:
    try:
        # get the next packets of all files 
        pkts = [next(x) for x in fds]
        # do something with them
    except EOFError:
        # file has ended
        break
for f in fds:
    f.close()
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to compare packet number X from file A with packet number Y from file B. Therefore getting the next packets is not sufficient.

Comment: Then it comes down to creating an algorithm that matches your needs. Maybe sort the elements in each file in the order you want to compare them, then iterate through the indexes (you could "skip" packets you don't use....) We can't really help further